# How to restart itself in Go daemon process?

Tags: linux, go, daemon, restart

I use [go-daemon](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon) library to fork process and run it in background. And I need to restart the daemon process after update performed from within http handler.

The handler code is

```
func httpUpdate(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if !isPost(req.Method) {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    if checkAuth(req) != 200 {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }

    log.Println("INFO: Update request, checking for update...")
    var err = doUpdate(UPDATE_URL, nil, false)
    if !isError(err) {
        log.Println("INFO: Update successful, exit")
        var system = RealSystem{}
        system.Run(fmt.Sprintf("(sleep 0.3s && %s start &> /test/extra.log)&disown", appFilename()))
        system.Exit(0)

        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
}
```

`doUpdate()` returns `nil` if successfully replaced the executable file. `RealSystem` is just wrapper for `exec.Command` and `os.Exit()`. `appFilename()` is the executable file name. The command to start app is `/path/to/app start`.

I see that new process starts, but executing `Context::Reborn()` fails with `EOF` error. Looks like some intrinsic pipes used as implementation details fail with `EOF` (may be...).

*What would be the reason? Or may be there is a better way of doing that?*

For now everything happens inside docker container in the "context" of e2e test if it matters. I spent hours trying to make it work but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is specific to the library. Spawn new self instance from within child process is not a problem for the system, but for that library.

To achieve this it's necessary to execute something like that.
Note the `_GO_DAEMON=0` variable set to zero. This makes library follow parent control flow.

```
var cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("sleep 0.5s; _GO_DAEMON=0 %s start", appFilename()))
var err = cmd.Start()
```

Also it was necessary to make small changes to the original library. Here is the [fork](https://github.com/yell0w4x/go-daemon).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean restarting the currently running Go binary. You can use a syscall for unix-based systems, and use an `exec.Command` for Windows.

```
func RestartSelf() error {
    self, err := osext.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    args := os.Args
    env := os.Environ()
    // Windows does not support exec syscall.
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        cmd := exec.Command(self, args[1:]...)
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
        cmd.Env = env
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err == nil {
            os.Exit(0)
        }
        return err
    }
    return syscall.Exec(self, args, env)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same. `Context::Reborn()` fails with `EOF`.